# Having set amount of thread to work as consumers

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have created a producer / consumer code as following

```
class CTest{
public:
    void producer( int i ){
        unique_lock<mutex> l(m);
        q.push(i);
        if( q.size() )
            cnd.notify_all();
    }

    void consumer(int i ){
        unique_lock<mutex> l(m);    
            while( q.empty() ){
                    cnd.wait(l );
                }
            if( q.empty())
                return;
            cout << "IM AWAKE :" << i  << endl;
            int tmp = q.front();
            q.pop();
            l.unlock();
            cout << "Producer got " << tmp << endl;
        }



    void ConsumerInit( int threads ){
        for( int i = 0; i < threads; i++ ){
            thrs.push_back(thread(&CTest::consumer, this ,i));
        }

    }
    void waitForTHreads(){
        for( auto &a : thrs )
            a.join();
    }
    void printQueue(){
        while( ! q.empty()){
            int tmp = q.front();
            q.pop();
            cout << "Queue got " << tmp << endl;
        }
    }
private:
    queue<int> q;
    vector<thread> thrs;
    mutex m;
    condition_variable cnd;
};
```

and main

```
int main(){
    int x;   
    CTest t;
    int counter = 0;
    while( cin >> x ){
        if( x == 0 ){
            cout << "yay" << endl;;
            break;
        }
        if( x == 1)
            t.producer(counter++);
        if( x == 2 )
            t.ConsumerInit(5);
    }   
    t.waitForTHreads();
    t.printQueue();
    return 0;
}
```

What this code does it , when user inputs "1" it will add number to the queue ,when user inputs "2" , 5 threads are spawned to retrieve data from queue and print it. However my problem is as followng , when i input
6 numbers , only 5 of them are printed due to fact that only 5 threads are spawned , what i want to do is thread to retrieve a data from queue , print int, and then again waiting if it can print another data. This way all N > 5 numbers would pri printed with just 5 threads.

My question is , what is standard way how to achieve this? I read few documens but didnt fint/cannot think of good solution. How are problems like this solved?

when i try to create simple thread pool :

```
void consumer(int i ){
    while(true){
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> l(m);    
            while( q.empty() ){
                    cnd.wait(l );
                }
            if( q.empty())
                return;
            cout << "IM AWAKE :" << i  << endl;
            int tmp = q.front();
            q.pop();

            cout << "Producer " << i << " got " << tmp << endl;
        }   //consumer(i);
    }
}
```

and input N number all numbers are processed by one thread.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Probably all your items got consumed by one thread because the thread finished processing them all before the next thread even got a chance to wake up.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of `consumer` can only read one value before exiting. In order to read more, it must loop, and this leads to  your second version of `consumer` which has two problems:

1. Consumption here is so quick that the first thread into the queue can consume the whole queue within its timeslice (or however CPU is being allocated). Insert a yield or a sleep to force the OS to switch tasks.
2. The mutex is not unlocked so no other threads are able to get in.

Fortunately you aren't creating the threads until you need them and they terminate after the queue is empty so the whole deal with `conditional_variable` can go out the window.

```
void consumer(int i)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> l(m);
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        int tmp = q.front();
        q.pop();
        cout << i << " got " << tmp << endl;
        // note: In the real world, locking around a cout is gross. cout is slow, 
        // so you want the unlock up one line. But...! This allows multiple threads
        // to write to the consle at the same time and that makes your output 
        // look like it was tossed into a blender, so we'll take the performance hit
        l.unlock(); // let other threads have a turn
        this_thread::yield();
        l.lock(); // lock again so the queue can be safely inspected
    }
}
```

If you need to go with the threadpool approach, things get a little messier and the condition variable makes a return.

```
void consumer(int i)
{
    while (true)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> l(m);
        if (q.empty())
        {
            cnd.wait(l);
        }
        if (!q.empty()) // OK. We got out of the conditional wait, but have 
                        // other threads sucked the queue dry? Better check.
        {
            int tmp = q.front();
            q.pop();
            cout << i << " got " << tmp << endl;
        }
        l.unlock();
        this_thread::yield();
    }
}
```

An `atomic<bool> terminated` may be helpful to allow an orderly shutdown `while (true)` does not allow for.

Answer (score 0):

In general, without going into code details, a threadpool is created and the threads are put in a wait state (waiting on one or more events / signals, or in your case `condition_variable cnd;`) - I'm used to work with events, so I'll use that in the following text, but a `condition_variable` should work in a similar way.

When a task is added to the queue, a task-event is set/fired and one ore more threads wake up (depending on the event (single / multi)).

When a thread wakes up, it checks (with a lock) if there is a task available, if available, executes the task and when finished checks again (!) if there are more tasks waiting. (because when you add 8 tasks in one go, 5 threads become active, so they need to check if there are more tasks after finishing their first one.

If there are no jobs left, the thread goes back in the wait state (waiting for a next job, or a quit event).

When quitting the application, another, say quit-event, is set for all threads (you can't just wait for the threads to finish, because the threads themselves are waiting on an event to do some work) -- or you could fire the same event, and first set a `volatile variable`, which the threads should then first check on any event to see if they need to quit, or do another job. Then you can wait for the threads to 'come home'.

A lock should be held as short as possible.

As for your code:

```
void producer( int i ){
    unique_lock<mutex> l(m);
    q.push(i);
    if( q.size() )
        cnd.notify_all();
}
```

Here the lock is held longer than needed (and perhaps too long). You also just pushed a value, so `q` will not be empty (no need to check). Since you only add one item (task), only one thread should be woken up (so `notify_one()` should be fine here).

So you should: `lock, push, unlock, notify` - instead of `unlock`, you can place the `lock` and `push` inside brackets, which will trigger an `unlock` in the `unique_lock<>` destructor.

```
void consumer(int i ){
    unique_lock<mutex> l(m);    
        while( q.empty() ){
                cnd.wait(l );
            }
        if( q.empty())
            return;
        cout << "IM AWAKE :" << i  << endl;
        int tmp = q.front();
        q.pop();
        l.unlock();
        cout << "Producer got " << tmp << endl;
}
```

Here you should `lock, check queue, pop if there is a task, unlock`, if no task, put the thread in a wait state again, else do work with the popped value (after unlocking), and then check again if there is more work to do. Normally it is not a good idea to call `cout` while the data is locked.. but for a small test you could get away with it, especially because `cout` needs to be synchronized too (but it would be cleaner to synchronize `cout` on its own, separate from your data lock).

```
void printQueue(){
    while( ! q.empty()){
        int tmp = q.front();
        q.pop();
        cout << "Queue got " << tmp << endl;
    }
}
```

Make sure your data is locked here too! (although it's only called from main after the threads have finished, the function is in your class, and the data should be locked).